# PHP Contact form input doesnt support diacritics

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have small problem with my php contact form code. 
I have my site using diacritics which does work perfectly. But my contact form input after submitting looks like this "ÄÅ¡Å" after using any [0-9] keys for diacritics.

PHP file:

```
<?php


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$service = $_POST['service'];      
$message = $_POST['message'];      

$from = $name; 
$to = 'info@email.com'; 
$subject = "$name - $service";

$body = "Jméno zákazníka: $name\nE-Mail zákazníka: $email\nTelefonní číslo: $phone\nservice: $service\nZpráva: $message ";

if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from, $headers)) {
    $headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}


?>
```

Email Output after submitting the contact form:

```
First Last Name

Jméno zákazníka: Name
E-Mail zákazníka: email
Telefonní císlo: phone number
service: havÃ¡rii
Zpráva: ÄÅ¡Å
```

the "headers" as name, email, phone, service, message is written with diacritics BUT then the input for example here: Zpráva: ÄÅ¡Å is not supported for some reason.

Also the html file include

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

UPDATE 1

Have tried to put $headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); before the contact form is submitted but no change were made. Still doesnt support any of these characters: ě š č ř ž ý á í é

MORE INFO

Adding also the html part where the problem is mostly visible

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Zpráva"> 
</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your submitting form also have UTF-8 character set specified?

Comment: @Philip I have my contact form in html file where is the <meta charset="utf-8"> already set in body.

Comment: @Ingus No, the form is focused on header with I have already set.

Comment: I think there some info is missing. ..

Comment: " input after submitting" ...where are you seeing it after submitting exactly? Your PHP does not appear to re-output any of the submitted data. Are you talking about what you see in the email?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, email output

Comment: right so it's the email display which isn't UTF-8 encoded, most likely. I note that you seem to have set the `$headers` variable **after** the email has already been sent.

Comment: @ADyson Oh, youre right, ill comeback! Thanks. great point

Comment: Note it’s `header()`, not `$headers = ();` they are very different! https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @ThomasEdwards So I must doing something wrong. it seems that when I place anywhere header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); it doesnt do anythign :/ Really lost. Have no Idea why the titles of name, email, phone, message is normal with diacritics but the input of user isnt showing up.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood where the problem is, have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your headers as the 4th param of `mail()`:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$service = $_POST['service'];      
$message = $_POST['message'];      

$from = $name; 
$to = 'info@email.com'; 
$subject = "$name - $service";

$body = "Jméno zákazníka: $name\nE-Mail zákazníka: $email\nTelefonní číslo: $phone\nservice: $service\nZpráva: $message ";

$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
    'From' => $from,
];

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "Sent";
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Note that this is for *plain text* email, not for HTML email.

`From` should be formatted as such: `Name <email@example.com>`, so if you don’t have information, then *do not include it*.

Comment: if OP wants HTML email why not give an example with that header instead?

Comment: Thank you for little explanation. Tried, still doesnt work. Getting same result. Also yes, I understand that this is used for plain text and its used like that.

Comment: I wonder if the problem can be when im getting the message "$message = $_POST['message'];  " or if the problem is in printing the message in here "$body = "Jméno zákazníka: $name\nE-Mail zákazníka: $email\nTelefonní číslo: $phone\nDruh servisu: $service\nZpráva: $message ";
" But the website is fully compatible with utf 8 and 0-9 characters

Comment: When you declare $body you are not printing anything, you're just concatenating a variable. I don't think the problem can occur at that point. It's only when you try to display it that encoding becomes an issue